# Is there a quick way to connect bluetooth headphones to Apple TV (4th gen) when the in-app menu doesn't support it?

Tags: bluetooth, appletv, headphones

Most apps allow me to quickly swipe down from the top of my "Siri Remote" and select my bluetooth headphones from the in-app menu but some apps (e.g. YouTube) don't offer that functionality so I have to dig into the Apple TV Settings to connect my headphones.

This is tedious - is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

When you're on the main menu or in the "TV" app you can press and hold the Play/Pause button which will bring up a simple menu for selecting your audio output from the available (powered on) devices:

[image]